# printing strings in array of strings in reverse order

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, multidimensional-array

So i did this program and the purpose is to store a string from the stdin and store in a array of strings. After that, i want to print all the strings stored in the array but in reverse order.

Example:

Input:

```
abc def hij klm nop
```

Output:

```
nop
klm
hij
def
abc
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLEN 1001

int main(){
    char buffer[MAXLEN];
    char** strings;
    int i = 0;
    int j = MAXLEN;
    strings = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*MAXLEN);
    while(scanf("%s",buffer) == 3)
    {
        strings[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer)+1));
        strcpy(strings[i],buffer);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s",strings[0]);
}
```

Well, i just put the 1st string only to check if it was printing any strings the problem is that if type that in the example it prints `(null)` instead of the word and what im wondering is why is it pointing to NULL instead of pointing to the string i gave.

Really any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the `scanf` manual page, it returns the *number of items successfully matched and assigned*. Your `"%s"` is looking for one item, so it's not going to return a 3. Where did you get 3 from? Try `scanf("%s",buffer) == 1`.

Comment: `strings = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*MAXLEN);` --> `MAXLEN` has nothing to do with the size needed.  It depends on the iteration count of the following loop.

Comment: @MartimCorreia: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for successful conversion from `stdin` is incorrect: `scanf()` returns the number of conversions, not the number of characters. You should compare the return value to `1`. As coded, the loop test fails immediately so `strings[0]` is not modified, the code has undefined behavior because the array allocated by `malloc` is uninitialized. This array happens to contain a null pointer at the beginning (because its first bytes are zero by coincidence), and `printf` prints `(null)` for null pointers, which is not guaranteed by the C Standard, but a useful indication sometimes.

Furthermore, you should tell `scanf()` about the maximum length of a word to store into the destination array: `scanf("%1000s", buf)`.

You should also limit the number of words you tore into the array of pointer and test for memory allocation error.

Finally, you need a loop to output the strings in reverse order of input.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 1001

int main() {
    char buffer[MAXLEN];
    int i, j;
    char **strings = malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAXLEN);
    if (strings == NULL)
        return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXLEN && scanf("%1000s", buffer) == 1; i++) {
        strings[i] = strdup(buffer);
        if (strings[i] == NULL)
            return 1;
    }
    for (j = i; j-- > 0;) {
        printf("%s\n", strings[j]);
        free(strings[j]);
    }
    free(strings);
    return 0;
}
```